# Jenkins 'Execute shell' build, executing python script fails randomly

Tags: python, linux, jenkins

I've done a lot of research before asking this question and couldn't find appropriate answer.

**Problem:** I have a set up where Jenkins executes python scripts on slave machine (Red Hat Linux 6.5). The real problem is my build fails with **'Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure'** . Sometimes it executes those scripts successfully and sometimes  fails. Their is no pattern in failing of build step. 
When i run these script from Slave machine's terminal manually, they work fine without any error or anything (i made those scripts).
My question is, **why** ?

**Things I've tried:**
1. Giving absolute path to the script in Jenkins.
2. Exception handling in scripts to show error msg, still no good in Jenkins
3. No changes/updates are made to the slave machine

**Environment Details:**
1. Running Jenkins on Windows 7(Master) machine by executing jenkins.war file
2. Python install on windows 7 machine 2.7.8 and 2.6.6 on Slave Red Hat 6.5
3. Slave machine is a VM in vSphere
4. Jenkins version tried 2.1 and 2.7.1

Thanks for the help and i appreciate your reply.

screenshots:
[Build Fail Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgoCU.png)
[Build Success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQfz6.png)

Comment: Is the problem that the script could not be executed at all, or that the script was executed but encountered some problem and returned a failure exit code?

Comment: @JohnGordon -scripts run in a try and catch code, so any error in the scripts can be caught. Moreover, i run these scripts manually in terminal like 100 times and they are pretty solid. Just Added Shcreenshots

Comment: When the errors occur, do the scripts produce an error message?  If so, are these error messages preserved somewhere so you can look at them and see what the real issue is?

Comment: @JohnGordon - From my understand, scripts do not give any error messages. It more looks like, jenkins fails to execute it. So no error message in scripts and Jenkins console shows 'Execute shell marked as failure'

Comment: >  Sometimes it executes those scripts successfully and sometimes fails.
Can you check if it is every alternate jenkins build? If yes, the python script you are running might have some side-effects. Even when it fails, it might be clearing up something that allows the build to succeed next time you run it.

Comment: Jenkins use the exit code. If it is non zero, it is a failure.

Comment: @geoji  - No, there is not pattern in failing. It can fail unexpectedly anytime. I cannot post more screenshot, but here are my build history from last 10 Builds (from 1st to 10th) : Fail, Fail, Success, Fail, Success, Success, Success, Fail, Success, Success (This executed today at 5 am).

Comment: @Jayan - I know jenkins uses exit code to mark build success or failure. But to get the exit code, it has to go thru my python scripts, right ? which it doesn't. How can it mark build **Fail** without even executing them (See screenshot above)

Comment: Maybe you could add some print statements to the Python script to get some idea of where in the script it is failing, or if it fails to execute the script at all.